# array of bytes to num

Tags: ruby, endianness

I have for example

```
tab = [0x51, 0x3c, 0xb8, 0x15]
```

then I want to convert this table to integer

```
0x15b83c51 = 363323840
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

```
> tab.reverse.inject("") {|s,a| s<<a.to_s(16) }.to_i(16)
 => 364395601
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with the bit/hex functions in ruby, so sorry if it's not more specific or precise, but... have you tried to:

```
bitnum = 0
while hexnum = tab.pop do
  # 1. convert hexnum to binary format
  # 2. bit-shift bitnum accordingly
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tab.reverse.inject {|s,a| (s<<8) + a}
# => 364395601
```

Answer (score 0):

(I have no idea how you get `363323840` from `0x15b83c51`. Like other people already answered, `0x15b83c51` is `364395601`)

Here is yet another solution, which also works if you have more than one integer to decode in your table.

```
# Convert to binary string
binaryString = [0x51, 0x3c, 0xb8, 0x15].map(&:chr).join 

# Convert the binary string to an unsigned integer array
# and take its first element 
number = binaryString.unpack("I").first
```